# How can I change the Title for a 3 segmented Control Segments, when I enter a view control?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

The Segment name is Entrada.
I am doing like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Entrada(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        setTitle("Action 1", forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
        setTitle("Action 2", forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
        setTitle("Action 3", forSegmentAtIndex: 2)
    }
```

I get errors... thow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Swift 3.0 use:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var entrada : UISegmentedControl!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  entrada.setTitle("Action 1", forSegmentAt: 0)
  entrada.setTitle("Action 2", forSegmentAt: 1)
  entrada.setTitle("Action 3", forSegmentAt: 2) 
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to connect the segmented control to an `IBOutlet` in Interface Builder, then you can write

```
@IBOutlet var entrada : UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  entrada.setTitle("Action 1", forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
  entrada.setTitle("Action 2", forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
  entrada.setTitle("Action 3", forSegmentAtIndex: 2) 
}
```

In Swift 3+ the syntax has been changed to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  entrada.setTitle("Action 1", forSegmentAt: 0)
  entrada.setTitle("Action 2", forSegmentAt: 1)
  entrada.setTitle("Action 3", forSegmentAt: 2) 
}
```

Comment: I hAVE done that below like this:

 @IBAction func Entrada(sender: UISegmentedControl) { code }

But no success :(

I get a messagem saying that Entrada has no setTitle member

Comment: This is an `IBAction` which is called when the segmented control is tapped, an `IBOutlet` is a reference to an UI element in interface Builder. Interpreting the title of your question you need `IBOutlet`

Comment: Done that but now it crashes... :(

Comment: Have you also connected the `IBOutlet` in Interface Builder by control-dragging to the class object (the little circle left from the declaration line must be dark)?

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that? I've been looking for it whithout success

Comment: The easiest way to create outlets is described in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code snippet to setup titles of your segment control. Just pass an array of string to set titles.

**Swift 4+**

```
func segmentWithTitles(titles : [String])  {
        self.friendsSegment.setTitle(titles[0], forSegmentAt: 0)
        self.friendsSegment.setTitle(titles[1], forSegmentAt: 1)
        self.friendsSegment.setTitle(titles[2], forSegmentAt: 2)
    }
```